# fillna() after .reset_index was used to create DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, missing-data

I have 3 dfs with call, message and internet data for some users. I used groupby to find the number of calls (or messages, or GB) used per user per month, and then used `.reset_index` to convert the MultiIndexes to DataFrames. Through further analysis, I noticed that for some user ids, there were NaN values because for some months, some active users did not make any calls, send any messages or used any data. To remedy that I tried to use `.fillna()` but it is not working, so when I pull a specific user_id with known NaN values for total_calls, it prints an empty dataframe.

I tried:

```
calls_mins_per_month.fillna({'duration':0}, inplace=True)
calls_mins_per_month['duration'] = calls_mins_per_month['duration'].fillna(0)
calls_mins_per_month['duration'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Here is my code for the DataFrame for calls per month per user:

```
#For each user, find the number of calls made and minutes used per month:
calls_mins_per_month = megaline_calls.groupby(['user_id', "call_month"]).agg({"call_id": len, "duration": "sum"})
calls_mins_per_month.rename(columns={'call_id':'total_calls'}, inplace=True)
calls_mins_per_month = calls_mins_per_month.reset_index()
#print(calls_mins_per_month['duration'].isna().count())
calls_mins_per_month.fillna({'duration':0}, inplace=True)
```

Could someone point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: please edit the post to include what your data looks like and what your code is showing and what it is exposed to do

Comment: Show the out put print(calls_mins_per_month['duration'].isna().count()) before fillna

Answer (score 0):

you can try some actions:

use the df.replace(' ','') probably is a empty space and is not recognized for the fillna() as a 'Nan' value
or check that the Nan values are not actually 'Nan' string, if so, then you can do df.replace('Nan', '')

hope you can solve it